# Why does this array have 14 elements instead of 13?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I am trying to figure out why this method uses 14 elements when there are only 13 cards in a deck. This is the method in question.

```
public int meldSets(){

int[] rankCount = new int[14];
for (Card c : this){
    rankCount[c.getRank()] +=1;
}
```

Comment: Because you are defining 14 elements - `new int[14];`, use 13 elements array instead - `new int[13];`

Comment: Well you allocated the 14 element array. Would a 13 element array have been sufficient?

Comment: We can't tell why without seeing the rest of the code. Maybe the author did this to be safe. Maybe there are more cards. Maybe there's a joker rank. Who knows? This can only be answered if you provide more information (code).

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the rest of the code, but I suspect there's a loop somewhere that's counting on the list being null-terminated.

Comment: Or maybe it's because ranks start from 1 (ace) whereas array indices start from 0, and the author though using the index 7 for the rank 8 was confusing.

Comment: @ronalchn I don't play card much, but I am sure "joker" is never consider as part of deck. Also, each deck cannot have 1 joker and joker doesn't have any rank, so 14 elements look pointless.

Answer (score 2):

An `int[14]` has 14 elements in it enumerated from 0 to 13. Arrays in Java and many other languages start at 0. You have a choice of always subtracting 1 from the face value to get the position in the array, or you can ignore the first position in the array.

You can find more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).